# How do I convert an OctetString into a readable String(C#)?

Tags: c#

I'm using a SNMP library for C# and it doesn't have a good documentation.
When I request a Date it's returning me a OctetString and I'm not sure what to do with it.

When I convert it to String it become this:
    07 DC 02 17 0F 14 0E 00 2D 02 00

Comment: You should mention which SNMP library you are using...

Comment: What is the library you are using? Pretty specific format

Comment: I think you need to turn it into a DateTime first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just a guess

```
var b= "07 DC 02 17 0F 14 0E 00 2D 02 00"
        .Split(' ')
        .Select(s => byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
        .ToArray();

int year =b[0]*256 + b[1];
int month = b[2];
int day = b[3];
int hour = b[4];
int min = b[5];
int sec = b[6];

DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);
```

**OUTPUT:** 2/23/2012 3:20:14 PM

---

**EDIT**

Now it is not a guess any more.
Here is the [SNMPv2-TC DateAndTime](http://www.webnms.com/net-snmp/help/developing_management_applications/datatypes/textual_conventions/tcs_dateandtime.html) format of the question

---

**EDIT-2**

```
var strdateTime = 
    String.Format("{0}/{1,2:00}/{2,2:00} {3,2:00}:{4,2:00}:{5,2:00}.{6,2:00} {7}{8,2:00}:{9,2:00} UTC",
            year,month,day,hour,min,sec,
            b[7],Convert.ToChar(b[8]),b[9],b[10]);
```

**OUTPUT**: 2012/02/23 15:20:14.00 -02:00 UTC

Comment: Yes, looks like a good guess. But it leaves a few bytes unaccounted for (milliseconds?)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [OctetString.ToString Method](http://www.docs.snmpsharpnet.com/current/html/M_SnmpSharpNet_OctetString_ToString.htm):

> Return string representation of the OctetStrig object. If
>   **non-printable** characters have been found in the object, output is a
>   hex representation of the string. (Overrides Object.ToString().)

Please make sure that there are no non-printable characters.

**Update**

More detailed information about the implementation: [OctetString.ToString() method](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/node/32).

Comment: Unfortunately the sample contains quite a few non-printables.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah thats because it's supposed to be an encoded timestamp and not a string.  he's doing something wrong and not giving us nearly enough information to be helpful